# Include white space when using split

Tags: java

Trying to split a string in java at commas.

```
String example = "This,Is, An, Example, Split, Palm Bay"
example.split(",");
```

Splits but stops once it hits white space, so my resulting String[] just contains "This" and "Is".

Below is the portion of my code that I am having problems with, if I have any white space in the input from the scanner, the split stops there.

```
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String customerDetails = scanner.next();
        String[] details = customerDetails.split(",");
        if(details.length < 5) {
            for(int i = 0; i < details.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(details[i]);
            }
            System.out.println("Cannot complete your request, it appears that you have not entered enough information");
            return;
        }
        if(directory.addCustomer(new CustomerType(details[0], details[1], details[2], details[3], details[4])))
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code in your question. Whatever the problem is, it's somewhere/something else. http://ideone.com/MyylFh

Comment: Mine contains `[This, Is,  An,  Example,  Split,  Palm Bay]`, the output of `Arrays.toString()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are using `scanner.next` which uses white space as a delimeter so you are actually only reading in the first section. It has nothing to do with the split.

Have a look at the [Oracle doc for Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html).

> "By default, a scanner uses white space to separate tokens."